# Android : Get Animation duration in code

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, objectanimator

**rotate_x.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" >

    <objectAnimator 
       android:valueFrom="180"
       android:valueTo="0"
       android:propertyName="rotationX"
       android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
       android:duration="1000" >
    </objectAnimator>


</set>
```

Below code logs -1 to logcat.

```
Log.e(TAG, "Animation duration : " + ((AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.anim.rotate_x)).getDuration());
```

Why is this? How can I get `AnimatorSet` duration in code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `computeDurationHint()` from the Animation class.

```
long duration = 0;
for(Animation a : yourAnimatorSet.getChildAnimations())
    duration += a.computeDurationHint();
```

The javadoc says:

> Compute a hint at how long the entire animation may last, in milliseconds. Animations can be written to cause themselves to run for a different duration than what is computed here, but generally this should be accurate.